# mysql while loop; select and insert

Tags: mysql, while-loop

I'm trying to move enums from a table into their own table, the easiest way would be to run an SQL query which I figured I might use a WHILE loop for, but having never used one before the below obviously doesn't work. Is it possible to do something as the following:

```
WHILE (SET @cat = (SELECT DISTINCT `category` FROM `tablename`))
DO
  BEGIN
   INSERT INTO `categories` (title) VALUES (@cat);
  END;
END WHILE;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why do you dont try to insert the categories direct like this:

```
INSERT INTO `categories`
(
    title
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    `category`
FROM `tablename`
```